# Firebase Functions and Notifications not working properly

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have used firebase functions to send notifications. The Firebase function is triggered when an action happens in my android app. It sometimes sends a notification and sometimes it does not. There is no error in the code as I have tested them thoroughly and the the log does not show any error. It simply does not send the notification sometimes. I can't understand why this is happening in some cases.

Log when notification is sent properly

```
11:44:03.928 AM myFunction Successfully sent message: { results: [ ...] }

11:43:36.328 AM myFunction  execution took 1002 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

11:43:36.304 AM myFunction Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

11:43:35.327 AM myFunction Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions

11:43:35.327 AM myFunction Function execution started
```

Log when function is triggered but notification not sent

```
10:55:57.710 AM myFunction Function execution took 920 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

10:55:57.688 AM myFunction Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

10:55:56.791 AM myFunction Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions

10:55:56.791 AM myFunction Function execution started
```

Please help regarding why the function is triggered and notification not sent sometimes and what should I do to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add to your question the entire Cloud Function code

Comment: It looks like you are not returning the Promise created by your code to send the notification.  If you don't return the Promise, your function may be terminated prematurely.  See [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details.